# Run C/C++ program via adb shell

Tags: android, gcc, android-ndk, adb, native

I want to run programs written in C/C++ and other languages in Android.
I don't want to use Java or JVM in this process, once it will affect my app performance, and the purposes I'm doing this would be lost.
Is this even possible? How can I do it?

I've already researched and all the answers I got are with JVM or Termux, but I don't want to do that, instead, I want to run my programs via `adb shell` in my rooted device.

Also, is there some limitation to this, or can I use this to every language that compiles on Linux? I would like to be able to do this to another languages like Rust or Golang.

Comment: basically the command line executable has to be cross-compiled for Linux-arm64 (or armv7) environment. For older NDK versions there was the possibility to provide a standard [standalone Linux build chain](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain) so you could simply configure and make standard C programs on Linux. A second problem of cross-compiled executable are shared libraries, some of them are a bit different, so building executables with statically linked libraries is the safest way.